# IE6 Auto margin works? How is this possible?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I'm just a bit CSSing, and I have this code:

```
#page
{
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

I have a div with id="page". I opened my page in IE6, and it just worked. Since when do auto margins work in IE6? Can somebody explain me why it works? Thanks

BTW my doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE6 *does* support centering via `margin:auto`, as long as the document is in standards mode not quirks mode.

IE6 was the first IE version to support it.

Comment: Well, that's just embarrassing.  I've been using `text-align: center` for IE6 for *years* because I thought it didn't support this.  +1